# Cannot create a connection to data source 'TfsOlapReportDS'

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, portal, dashboard

When I open my project dashboard on my TFS project portal web page, I get the following error.

**Reporting Services Error**

> Cannot create a connection to data source 'TfsOlapReportDS'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection) A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had checked that SQL Server Analysis Services was running in

> Control Panel → Administrative Tools → Services

The service was running. The solution to this was that I needed to go into

> Start → Programs → Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 → SQL Server Configuration Manager → SQL Server Services.

That instance of SQL Server Analysis Services wasn't Running. I started it, and this prevented the error message above.